# non centered slides with Prosper

Tags: compiling, presentations

I use MixTeX 2.9 with Windows. I have a problem when compiling with the Prosper document class. My code begins as follows:

```
\documentclass[pdf,distiller]{prosper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\title{Multiple Response Optimization}
\subtitle{}
\author{St\'ephane Laurent}

\begin{document}

...
```

I compile with 1) latex, 2) dvips, and 3) ps2pdf. In the pdf file the slide is not well centered:

[image: slide]

I have tried several options with dvips but nothing changes.

Comment: The `prosper` class and its companion patching package `HA-prosper` are no longer maintained, as far as I know; the authors recommend to use `powerdot` instead.

Comment: Right, and I have finally switched to powerdot.